# Flutter: How can I make an button to show a random by me defined stateless Widget?

Tags: flutter

I have an button, and when it gets pressed, an `stateless Widget` consisting of an `Column` with a few `Text` and an `Image.Asset` is shown. So now I have a few of these `stateless Widgets`with different content. When I press the button, i want him now to show a ramdom one of these `stateless Widgets`, maybe an option for a specific order too.
How do I do that?

`Button` and comamnd for showing the Widget at the moment:

```
body: Center(
          child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
              children: <Widget>[
                if (isShown == true) Zauberwuerfel(),
                SizedBox(
                  width: 150,
                  height: 100,
                ),
                Container(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 60),
                  width: 230,
                  height: 130,
                  child: RaisedButton(
                      color: Colors.red,
                      child: Text('Skill', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 30)),
                      onPressed: () {
                        setState(() {
                          isShown = true;
```

One of those `stateless Widgets`:

```
class SkillJonglieren extends StatelessWidget {
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(children: <Widget>[
      Text(
        'Jonglieren',
        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 35),
      ),
      SizedBox(
        width: 20,
        height: 25,
      ),
      Image.asset('images/jonglieren.jpg', scale: 5),
      SizedBox(
        width: 20,
        height: 30,
      ),
      Row(mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center, children: <Text>[
        Text(
          'Schwierigkeit:',
          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 25),
        ),
        Text(
          ' Einfach',
          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 25, color: Colors.green),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Random class](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/1.24.3/dart-math/Random-class.html) to generate a random number.

- The range of the random will always be equal to the number of `StatelessWidget` you have
- You store a List which will keep your `StatelessWidget`
- When the button is pressed, you get the random number, and then pick up the index based upon that random number generated

**Assumptions:** Let us assume you have `5` StatelessWidgets namely `Widget1()`, `Widget2()`, `Widget3()`, `Widget4()` and `Widget5()`

Let us quickly jump into the code

```
import 'dart:math';

// Each Widget is located at an index which is unique
int randomNumber;
List<Widget> _widgets = [Widget1(), Widget2(), Widget3(), Widget4(), Widget5()];

// generating random number
void _generateRandomNumber(){
   var random = new Random();

   // now the range works like 0 to n-1
   setState(() => randomNumber = random.nextInt(_widgets.length));
}


//Triggering the function when showing the item
RaisedButton(
   color: Colors.red,
   child: Text('Skill', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 30)),
   onPressed: () {
      //calling our method
      _generateRandomNumber();

      setState(() => isShown = true);
   }
)
```

Now showing the data finally

```
Column(
   mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
   children: <Widget>[
     if (isShown == true) _widgets[randomNumber]
     ....
   ]
)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! But now I got the error "type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<Widget>' of 'function result'". How can I solve it?

Comment: Can you show me your `function result` please @Cedric ?

Comment: Oh I found the mistake myself. the "_" before "widgets" was missing. But thank you, because finally everything is working!

Comment: Hahaha! Be vigilant my friend @Cedric. Keep hustling. All the very best :)

Answer (score 1):

Assign random numbers with the `rand()` function in `dart:math` to some variables. then use condition.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to make your main widget a `StateFulWidget` since you want to toggle the `isShown` variable and make changes to the views. Then you need to make a list of Widgets(e.g., Widget1 and Widget2) in your main widget(which has the button in):

`final List<Widget> widgets = [Widget1(), Widget2()];`

To select one of these widgets randomly you can use:

`(widgets..shuffle()).first`

You need to select a new random widget in `onPressed`. To show the selected widget only when `isShown` is true, you can use a `Visibility` widget(the `if` method that you're using is ok, too). Finally set the child of this `Visibility` widget to the selected widget.

Full code:

```
final List<Widget> widgets = [Zauberwuerfel(), SkillJonglieren()];
var _isShown = false;
Widget _selectedWidget = Zauberwuerfel();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.grey,
        body: Center(
          child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
              children: <Widget>[
                Visibility(
                  visible: _isShown,
                  child: _selectedWidget,
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  width: 150,
                  height: 100,
                ),
                Container(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 60),
                  width: 230,
                  height: 130,
                ),
                RaisedButton(
                  color: Colors.red,
                  child: Text('Skill', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 30)),
                  onPressed: () {
                    setState(() {
                      _isShown = true;
                      _selectedWidget = (widgets..shuffle()).first;
                    });
                  },
                )
              ]),
        ));
  }
```